# How to get Alias from contact properties

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get the Alias ID of every received email from the sender's email address.
To get Alias you can right click on the received email, select open Outlook Properties.

I built a code that extracts email received in my inbox from a particular date specified in cell B.
I am trying to add the Alias ID in D4 onwards.

```vb
Sub GetFromOutlook()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim olExchgnUser    As ExchangeUser
     
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("insert your own email address").Folders("inbox")

    i = 1

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value Then
            Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject

            ''Alias this is where i'm attempting to get Alias as part of the loop from every Item
            Dim olNameSpace     As Namespace
            Dim olAddrList      As AddressList
        
            Set olAddrList = OutlookNamespace.AddressLists("Global Address List")
            Set olExchgnUser = olAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
            With olExchgnUser
                Range("Alias_name").Offset(i, 0) = .Alias
            End With
            ''''ENd Alias

            Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
            Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
            Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
            Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
            Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
            Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
            Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
            Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next OutlookMail

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "operation Complete"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Not having Exchange, I can't help you, but what about the answers to similar questions on this forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the lines

```
 Set olAddrList = OutlookNamespace.AddressLists("Global Address List")
 Set olExchgnUser = olAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
```

with

```
 Set olExchgnUser = OutlookMail.Sender.GetExchangeUser
```

(null and error handling omitted).

You really should not be looping through all messages in a folder - use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`.